# How can I build iterator for object that I have created in C++

Tags: c++, object, iterator

I want to build a simple iterator, for example - in the class: "myVector":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define maxSize 10

class myVector {
private:
    int *arr;
    int sp;
public:
    myVector() {
        arr = new int[maxSize];
        sp = 0;
    }
    bool add(int num) {
        if (sp==maxSize) return 0;
        arr[sp] = num;
        sp++;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

in the Example - I built a class that produces objects of type myVector. Now I want to build iterator with an operator ++ to run on the private Array of the vector.

thank you very much

Comment: Put typedef int* iterator, iterator begin() { return arr; } and iterator end() { return arr + sp; }  into myVector (similar applies to const_iterator) - Note, a pointer is an iterator

Answer (score 2):

You must support `std::iterator_traits<YourIterator>`.  The easy way is to inherit from `std::iterator<?>` with the appropiate arguments.

In doing so you have to decide on an iterator category.  This determines what you guarantee to support, both operator wise and behaviour wise.

Now, `boost` has some helper types to make writing an iterator a tad easier.  Consider using `boost`.  But a basic iterator is not impossible to write without them.

In the particular case above, a pointer is a valid iterator for your problem.  And easier than either of the above options.  Use this as your first iteration: KISS.  Note that pointers have `std::iterator_traits` support for free.

To make your object iterable (and support `for(auto&&x:c)` syntax), either write a free `begin` and `end` function in the same namespace as your class that produces iterators, or add `begin()` and `end()` methods that do the same.  I tend to also add `size` and `empty` and `front` and `back` as I find them useful.  As an example:

```
T& back(){return *std::prev(end());}
T const& back()const{return *std::prev(end());}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write something like this.

```
class myVector {
  class myIterator {
    private:
        int *position; //operator ++ increment this position
    public:
        myIterator operator++(){ 
           //increment position here 
        }
        int& operator*(){ 
          //return *pos 
        }
        bool operator==(const myIterator &it)const {
           //check that pos and it.pos are the same
        }
   };
};
```

This will work but wont be a STL compliant iterator, for that you will also need to add several typedefs, to say for instance the type of your iterator (in your case you have an input iterator). If you want an STL iterator the easiest thing is to use  [boost facade iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#the-problem).